# C - Load linked list from file

Tags: c, file

So im using binary files to save info about the state of some nodes (something internal of the system). The point is this binary files are just a lot of 1 and 0 and the idea is to read the file and load it into a struct.
This is the definition of the struct:

```
typedef struct t_bitmap{
int estado;
struct t_bitmap* siguiente;
}t_bitmap;
```

And this is the code that is supposed to load it:

```
t_bitmap leerBitmap(char* unPath){
    t_bitmap bitmap;
    FILE *fp = fopen (unPath, "rb");
    int i=0;
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    int tamanio = sizeof(char) * ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char* bytes = malloc(tamanio);
    fread(bytes, tamanio, 1, fp);
    fclose (fp);
    while(i<tamanio){
        bitmap.estado = bytes[i];
        bitmap = bitmap.siguiente; //This fails
        i++;
    };
    free(bytes);
    return bitmap;
};
```

---

EDIT 1

The error is:
incompatible types when assigning to type ‘t_bitmap’ from type ‘struct t_bitmap *’

Comment: Good. And you're here because... ?

Comment: The pointer `struct` member is relevant only in context. You  can't validly read them from a file - if you get that far.

Comment: @zerkms i dont know how to travel through the bitmap giving values to each estado. I pointed out which line fails.

Comment: sure that you want a linked list rather than an array of ints?

Comment: Also what is the value of bitmap.siguiente, do you set it somewhere? It looks uninitialized which is probably causing your crash.

Comment: @StephanLechner yes.

Comment: @Claris The error is: t_bitmap cant be assigned struct t_bitmap*

Comment: siguiente is a pointer to a t_bitmap. And the variable bitmap of type t_bitmap isn't compatible with a pointer.

Comment: Need `malloc` for `t_bitmap` for each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate a new node for each byte you read in.

Usually one would define the function such that it returns a pointer to the head of a linked list (which could be `NULL` if no value can be read in).

In order not to change the prototype of your function, I kept the "return-by-value"-metaphor for the head of the list.

So the function allocates a new node for each byte, except for the first byte, which is stored directly in the "head" that will be returned by value:

```
t_bitmap leerBitmap(char* unPath){
    t_bitmap bitmap;
    FILE *fp = fopen (unPath, "rb");
    int i=0;
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    int tamanio = sizeof(char) * ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char* bytes = malloc(tamanio);
    fread(bytes, tamanio, 1, fp);
    fclose (fp);

    t_bitmap* curBitMap = &bitmap; // the current bitmap to write to
    while(i<tamanio){
        if (i > 0) { // except for the first, create a new node
            curBitMap->siguiente = malloc(sizeof(t_bitmap));
            curBitMap = curBitMap->siguiente;
        }
        curBitMap->estado = bytes[i];
        curBitMap->siguiente = NULL;
        i++;
    };
    free(bytes);
    return bitmap;
}
```